# Visual Studio 2012 design an Outlook 2003 add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, outlook-2003, netoffice

I'm currently looking for a way to make an Outlook 2003 add-in in C# with my Visual Studio 2012.  Everywhere I look for this on the internet says that earlier versions of Visual Studio will do this however I would ideally like to use VS2012.  Has anyone had to do this to support legacy clients like myself?  And how did you get around this?

I've found NetOffice - MS Office in .NET - http://netoffice.codeplex.com/
but have never used this and it seems like it's not as straight forward.

Comment: It's a outlook form addin.  For a ticket system that will send a email based off of a series of drop down boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use NetOffice and it worked flawlessly.  Just a FYI.